# Invalid command 'VirtualDocumentRoot'

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm unsure as to why I'm getting the following error when apache is rebooted:

`Invalid command 'VirtualDocumentRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'start' failed.`

The snippet it is referring to is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin help@mydomain.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /local/www/staging/%1

        ServerAlias *.staging.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I assumed it was a misspelling as it said, but it was copied directly from another server of mine. It works perfect there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[The documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot) suggests that the directive is provided by the module vhost_alias.  You should ensure that you have the

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

configuration directive in the configuration file of the server where it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me solve it. The code you posted didn't work directly, but I loaded the module using: `a2enmod vhost_alias`

Comment: Good for you, for starting from a hint and digging harder - that way lies excellence!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error as Andy provided, but in my case, the situation is a bit different. And from the answer of MadHatter, I could devise the problem.

My apache2 server was a bit different. It has 2 directories namely `/etc/apache2/mods-available` & `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`. Within directory `mods-available` you'll see a list of loadable module config file, in this case, I see a file named `vhost_alias.load` which contains the configuration as

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

So that, I used below command to enable this configuration:

```
sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
```